# Is it possible to manipulate the way TestCafe summarises results at end of test run?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

When I run 3 tests with TestCafe with planned various results, I get the following default results style:

```
 1/2 failed (1m 10s)
 1 skipped
```

But is it possible for me to manipulate this output to something like:

```
Total: 3, Passed:1, Failed:1, Skipped:1
```

Reason for this question is that I'm integrating Jenkins plugin 'Build Failure Analyzer' to push each test run summary to Jenkins plugin 'Build Monitor'. And the 'Build Failure Analyzer' searches through the build log, one line at a time, for a regular expression i.e. '.*Total'

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

TestCafe outputs the test results using [reporters](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/reporters.html). You mentioned the output of the default [spec](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-reporter-spec) reporter.
The output format is hardcoded inside of the reporter.
The simplest way to meet your needs - clone the [spec](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-reporter-spec) reporter repository, make necessary changes and setup the updated reporter as described [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/).